# Update join with multiple rows

Tags: r, data.table

### Question

When doing an update-join, where the `i` table has multiple rows per key, how can you control which row is returned?

### Example

In this example, the update-join returns the last row from `dt2`

```
library(data.table) 

dt1 <- data.table(id = 1) 
dt2 <- data.table(id = 1, letter = letters) 

dt1[ 
    dt2 
    , on = "id" 
    , letter := i.letter 
    ] 

dt1
#    id letter
# 1:  1      z
```

How can I control it to return the 1st, 2nd, nth row, rather than defaulting to the last?

---

### References

A couple of references similar to this by user @Frank

- [data.table tutorial](http://franknarf1.github.io/r-tutorial/_book/tables.html#joins-update) - in particular the 'warning' on update-joins
- [Issue on github](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2022)

Comment: If you sort `dt2` going into the join, you can somewhat control it - `dt2[order(letter,decreasing=TRUE),] `. I guess this is somewhat flexible too - `dt2[dt2[,.I[2],by="id"]$V1 ,]` for instance to take the 2nd value. But this is far from ideal in both cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most flexible idea I can think of is to only join the part of `dt2` which contains the rows you want. So, for the second row:

```
dt1[ 
    dt2[, .SD[2], by=id]
    , on = "id" 
    , letter := i.letter
    ]

dt1
#   id letter
#1:  1      b
```

With a hat-tip to @Frank for simplifying the sub-select of `dt2`.

Comment: @Frank - nice... i was under the impression that using `.SD[n]` was a no-no for efficiency. That obviously seems to have been optimised at some stage.

Comment: Yeah, maybe from partially-completed https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/735

Answer (score 6):

> How can I control it to return the 1st, 2nd, nth row, rather than defaulting to the last?

Not elegant, but sort-of works:

```
n = 3L
dt1[, v := dt2[.SD, on=.(id), x.letter[n], by=.EACHI]$V1]
```

A couple problems:

1. It doesn't select using GForce, eg as seen here:

   ```
   > dt2[, letter[3], by=id, verbose=TRUE]
   Detected that j uses these columns: letter 
   Finding groups using forderv ... 0.020sec 
   Finding group sizes from the positions (can be avoided to save RAM) ... 0.000sec 
   lapply optimization is on, j unchanged as 'letter[3]'
   GForce optimized j to '`g[`(letter, 3)'
   Making each group and running j (GForce TRUE) ... 0.000sec 
      id V1
   1:  1  c
   ```
2. If `n` is outside of `1:.N` for some joined groups, no warning will be given:

   ```
   n = 40L
   dt1[, v := dt2[.SD, on=.(id), x.letter[n], by=.EACHI]$V1]
   ```

Alternately, make a habit of checking that `i` in an update join `x[i]` is "keyed" by the join columns:

```
cols = "id"
stopifnot(nrow(dt2) == uniqueN(dt2, by=cols))
```

And then make a different `i` table to join on if appropriate

```
mDT = dt2[, .(letter = letter[3L]), by=id]
dt1[mDT, on=cols, v := i.letter]
```